# 404 - A public action method X was not found on controller Y (ActionInvoker.InvokeAction returns false)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

This is NOT a duplicate question, and the problem is driving me crazy. I am getting the typical error "A public action method X was not found on controller Y" which returns a `404 Not Found`. The screenshot gives you a good idea:

[image: Visual Studio debugging session]

**The image shows the debugger paused right before the line that throws the exception is executed** (`base.HandleUnknownAction(actionName)`). Now, before you jump into conclusions, here's some info:

1. This was working at some point perfectly well.
2. The HTTP verb (`GET`) should be accepted by the `UpdateCart` action (see annotations above method signature).
3. The parameters sent are irrelevant: the error happens with `POST`, `GET` and any combination of parameters.
4. Other similar actions in the same controller work well.
5. I took the screenshot with `UpdateCart` marked `virtual`, but removing `virtual` makes no difference.
6. **The screenshot shows that `ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(this.ControllerContext, "UpdateCart")` returns false**. Not sure why the reflection performed over my controller can't find the method, but it's RIGHT THERE!!

The routes are the default ones and they work, since otherwise I wouldn't have been able to stop the debugger to take the screenshot above. Here's the code from `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Tickets", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );

}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Ethan Brown's answer below is correct: `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` are mutually exclusive. The solution was to replace these attributes with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]`.

Comment: Are you doing any url rewriting?

Comment: Nope. No URL rewriting. Note how far the debugger got to!

Comment: +1 for a well phrased and documented question.  No ideas though other than the magic clean/rebuild solution trick.  sorry.

Comment: This smells like MVC bug.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying both the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` attributes.  If you leave both of them off, the action accepts both POST and GET requests.  My guess is that the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` attributes don't signal to MVC to allow the corresponding request type, but to *deny* the opposite type.  So by including `[HttpPost]`, you're denying GET requests, and by including `[HttpGet]`, you're denying POST requests...effectively denying all request types.  Leave the attributes off and it will accept both types.

**Update**: I just checked the MVC source, and my assumption is correct.  In `ActionMethodSelector`, it checks the attributes thusly:

```
if (attrs.All(attr => attr.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo))) {
    matchesWithSelectionAttributes.Add(methodInfo);
}
```

In other words, all `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` (from which `HttpPostAttribute` and `HttpGetAttribute` derive) must return true for the action to be invoked.  One or the other is always going to return false, so the action will never execute.

Comment: Is this the same for both `using System.Web.Http;` and `using System.Web.MVC` ? i.e. does the `using System.Web.Http;` also signal 'deny' or is this specific to the mvc version? I ask because I just took out the verbs from a api project and a normal website project. The website one behaves as you described but the api project without any verbs can not longer find the action at all (it had both get and post attached)... so either `System.Web.Http` acts differently, or something else is causing it in my route binder.... :S

Comment: Your guess that the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` attributes signal to MVC to deny the opposite type is not quite correct.  By adding any of the http verb attributes you are indicating that the method ONLY supports that verb.  so the first one listed executes and denies the request if it's not the right verb.  This is why `AcceptVerbs` works, because it allows a list.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out: in my case I was getting a 500 error when trying to reach a new action method.

> IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.0 - A public action method 'getwells' was
>   not found on controller
>   'ITVizion.VizionLogs.Widgets.Controllers.MapController'.

I added the action method to the Controller and was "deploying" the updated app to IIS.

The problem: I was deploying the `Debug` configuration in Visual Studio and had unchecked that specific project from building. That was to speed up building in Visual Studio since there are lots of project in the solution. :D Going to the IIS app folder I saw that the project's DLL was outdated.

So make sure you check the project to Build. :) This will obviously take care of deploying the new codez to IIS.

[image]