# Valums file uploader cant find my controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, valums-file-uploader

On [GitHub](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) they have asp.net mvc demo. Not full project but controller/class/binder.

I downloaded their code, there is test folder with no dependency demo and jquery demo.

I also made my controller/action as on their demo.

```
 public partial class UploadController : MyController
{
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload, string extraParam1, int extraParam2)
        {
            // asp.net mvc will set extraParam1 and extraParam2 from the params object passed by Fine-Uploader

            var dir = @"e:\temp\";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, upload.Filename);
            try
            {
                upload.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new FineUploaderResult(false, error: ex.Message);
            }

            // the anonymous object in the result below will be convert to json and set back to the browser
            return new FineUploaderResult(true, new { extraInformation = 12345 });
        }
}
```

On their test demo page, i change  endpoint parameter to

```
 endpoint: "http://localhost:60784/upload/uploadfile"
```

But heh, how i get exception like

```
A public action method 'uploadfile' was not found on controller     'MaNameSpace.Controllers.UploadController'.
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you configure the File Upload plugin? MyController is your base controller, right?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi http://prntscr.com/sm3ww , this is from their demo page

Comment: What's that MyController that you inherit?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi some custom functions, changing to base Controller, this same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Try adding a last slash to the endpoint URL: `http://localhost:60784/upload/uploadfile/`
2. Change `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` and see if the action method gets hit.

Using Firebug on Firefox open at the Network tab, you can take a look at the request that's being made to the server and check if the File Upload plugin is issuing a Get or Post request.

Comment: Heh now u total confuse me. Changing to [HttpGet] calls my action. On Chrome inspect element network request type is "OPTIONS" http://prntscr.com/sm6xx and since its not "POST" my ImputStream is always null/empty http://prntscr.com/sm71s

Comment: uhmmm... So you can do what's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008013/114029 or remove the `AcceptVerb` from the action method as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9932926/114029

Comment: If the above doesn't work, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14333621/114029